# Azure Web Role Mutliple Deployment Slots

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I know Web Roles have a staging and production deployment slots but is it possible to have dev, test, staging and production deployment slows with Web Roles in the same way Website are, or do I need to have multiple Web Roles for dev and test?

Answer (score 2):

Azure cloud services support only the staging and production slots. To ensure isolation of user roles many organizations go as far as hosting dev, test and production cloud services in separate Azure subscriptions to get round the lack of RBAC in the current production portal and service management REST API.

Comment: I find the dual subscription a little crazy since Websites have 5 different deployment slots...